How do I implement a RESET component on tinkercad?
I want to do a reset implementation. When I click on the pressure button I want my machine to go the my initial state which is 0110 and without pressing the button it should be in the state 1111.
The 74hc73 chip doesn't have the preset pin.
Can someone tell me what I can do to fix this? I can force the 0110 state but I don't know how to force the 1111 state. I also can't understand how to make the pressure button work.
This is the link to my project:https://www.tinkercad.com/things/5fqBw9wkziV-reset/editel?returnTo=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tinkercad.com%2Fdashboard%2Fdesigns%2Fcircuits&sharecode=cYRbQNiuNzgnMc8cV80CZe2U0Jm-DQdYdtc6erHYwGQ

start by learning how to detect a button press
